# Bash: comparing a string as an integer

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, compare

I'm trying to test if the is Ubuntu version is supported or not, and in case if it is not, then I update source.list in APT folder

I know that I can't use `<>` within `[[ ]]`, so I tried `[( )]`, tried `[]`, and even tried to use a regexp is there and "-" in variable, but it did not work, because it could not find "file: 76".

How should I write the comparison to work?

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(cat /etc/issue | grep -o "[0-9]" | tr -d '\n') #Get Version String
yre=$(echo "$output" | cut -c1-2) #Extract Years
month=$(echo "$output" | cut -c3-4) #Extract Months
##MayBe move it to function
yearMonths=$(($yre * 12)) #TotlaMonths
month=$(($month + $yearMonths)) #Summ
##End MayBe

curMonths=$(date +"%m") #CurrentMonts
curYears=$(date +"%y") 

##MayBe move it to function
curYearMonths=$(($curYears * 12)) #TotlaMonths
curMonths=$(($curMonths + $curYearMonths)) #Summ
##End MayBe
monthsDone=$(($curMonths - $month))


if [[ "$(cat /etc/issue)" == *LTS* ]]
then
  supportTime=$((12 * 5))
else
    supportTime=9
fi

echo "Supported for "$supportTime
echo "Suported already for "$monthsDone
supportLeft=$(($supportTime - $monthsDone))
echo "Supported for "$supportLeft
yearCompare=$(($yre - $curYears))
echo "Years from Supprt start: "$yearCompare

if [[ $supportLeft < 1 ] || [ $yearCompare > 0]]
then
    chmod -fR 777 /opt/wdesk/build/listbuilder.sh 
    wget -P /opt/wdesk/build/ "https://placeofcode2wget.dev/listbuilder.sh"
    sh /opt/wdesk/build/listbuilder.sh
else
    echo "Still Supported"
fi
```

Comment: As an aside, to avoid the [UUCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) there, try `output=$(grep -o "[0-9]" /etc/issue)` (yeah, the `tr` is also completely superfluous here). You should probably `grep` for more than a single digit, too, I guess?

Comment: Actually, getting a machine-readable version from [`lsb_release`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release) is much simpler and more reliable than attempting to parse `/etc/issue`.

Comment: @tripleee possible, as I said I'm bewbie , so thank you for warning (about UUCA). lsb_release made some warning messages, so I skipped it, but guess I'll reconsider that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like this:

```
[[ $supportLeft -lt 1 || $yearCompare -gt 0 ]]
```

You can find these and other related operators in `man test`

Comment: You need a space between the `0` and `]]`

Comment: Ah, yes... I overlooked that when copy-pasted. Thanks!

Comment: :( Same Error that I've had with "if (( $supportLeft < 1 || $yearCompare > 0 ))"...

Comment: Worked like : [[ "$supportLeft" -lt 1 ] || [ "$yearCompare" -gt 0 ]] ... Thank you all :)

Comment: Unless this is something new in `bash` 4, I'm pretty sure that syntax is plain wrong... You can't pair up `[[` with `]` like that...

Comment: Fixed. Weird. I don't know how that happened. +1 for pointing out!

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is any help, but this question was high in Google when I searched for "compare string to int in bash"

You can "cast" a string to an int in bash by adding 0

```
NUM="99"
NUM=$(($NUM+0))
```

This works great if you have to deal with NULLs as well

```
NUM=""
NUM=$(($NUM+0))
```

Make sure there aren't any spaces in the string!

```
NUM=`echo $NUM | sed -e 's/ //g'`
```

(Tested on Solaris 10)

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
if (( $supportLeft < 1 )) || (( $yearCompare > 0 ))
```

or

```
if (( $supportLeft < 1 || $yearCompare > 0 ))
```

Comment: :( Tried , but it enden with 3 notices (I guess) : cannot open 1 , file not found; 993 not found ; 72 not found; .. It looks like it is related to $yearsCompare => 72 , 1 to 1 and 993 to $supportLeft . Had something like that Today before... Any idea about that??

Answer (score 2):

BaSH conditionals are - when it comes to numbers and arithmetic - terribly confusing.

Either of these methods will work:

```
if [ $((supportLeft)) -lt 1 ] || [ $((yearCompare)) -gt 0 ]
```

or

```
if (( supportLeft < 1 || yearCompare > 0 ))
```

Note both methods treat null values as zero. Depending on your script and environment, this may be advantageous in the sense they won't generate an error message if the value of the variable on either side of the equation is null.